# How to keep ngCookies after closing browser?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I want to keep my ngCookies after I close the browser. 
After some research I tried this solution:

```
var expireDate = new Date();
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
$cookies.put('authenticated', true, {expires: expireDate});
```

But it sadly only works on F5(refresh).
How can I keep the cookies after closing my browser?

Comment: Am I wrong, or are you setting the cookie to expire 1 millisecond after the current time?

Comment: @AlonEitan it sets the expireDate 1 day later with setDate()

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Oh, thanks for clarify it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use $cookiesProvider to change the default behavior of the $cookies service.
>
> expires - {string|Date} - String of the form "Wdy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT" or a Date object indicating the exact date/time this cookie will expire.

Reference : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults